# Haskell read function report error couldn't match expected type

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner and I was trying to write a function that check if a string can be interpreted to number or not. Here is my code:

```
string' xs = if (all isDigit xs == False)
             then "can not be interpreted"
             else read xs::Int
```

But it keeps reporting the error " Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’ "
I don't know why, has someone ever met this problem?

Comment: What is the type of `string'` - is it `string' :: String -> String` or `string' :: String -> Int`?

In haskell, you can't have a function that returns one of two different types based on runtime properties of the input.

Comment: You might also like `reads :: String -> [(Int, String)]`, which will check that the input is well-formed for you, returning `[]` if not (and a list with the successful parse and whatever was left unparsed if so).

Comment: Style comment: consider using `not (...)` instead of `(...) == False`. This is a matter of taste, but the first looks more "natural". Alternatively, remove that completely and swap the then/else branches. (Daniel's suggestion above about `reads` would be even better.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both branches of your if-then-else need to have the same type.  Your "then" branch has type `[Char]` and your "else" branch has type `Int`.  It seems like your "then" branch should result in some sort of error.  In this case you can use [error](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:error), which has a polymorphic type and can be used instead.

A better solution (suggested in the comment section) would be to use the [Either](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Either.html) type, which can return one of two options (`Left` or `Right`).

```
string' xs = if (all isDigit xs == False)
             then Left "can not be interpreted"
             else Right (read xs::Int)
```

Another common thing to do would be to use the [Maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Maybe.html) type

```
string' xs = if (all isDigit xs == False)
             then Nothing
             else Just (read xs::Int)
```

Comment: Sure, or the OP could use `Either String Int` as the return type and return `Left "can not ..."` or `Right (read xs :: Int)`.